# Vuejs endpoint configuration

Tags: configuration, vue.js

I'm really new in VueJS, 
I use RxJS, Vue rx and Vue Resource in a mixin so i can make http calls and get observables back anywhere... awesome!
now i tried

```
 subscriptions () {
  return {
    titles$: this.getHTTPObservable('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/albums').flatMap(arr => Rx.Observable.from(arr).take(10).map(o => o.title).toArray())
  }
```

The only thing i need now is to specify the end point of the server i am requesting in some configuration file like i would do in angular environments file. When launching the build by hand it should look like when i write

```
ng serve --env=dev
```

is there something similar?

Answer (score 1):

Actually i found the answer on this page https://vuejs-templates.github.io/webpack/env.html

so, i can add any configuration variable and then call process.env.varname to get it back,
thanks

Answer (score 0):

Vue.js normally works in conjunction with Webpack to achieve this.

https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/deployment.html#With-Build-Tools

The DefinePlugin from Webpack is used for this. Outside of Webpack I think you are still able to use this:

https://www.npmjs.com/package/cross-env